# Instagram Python Requests

Tags: python, instagram

So basically I am trying to learn python parsing through Instagram API.
First I am trying to get the link of the posts based on tags then I am trying to get the usernames using selenium.

I am facing a problem, when I send multiple requests I am getting some JSON error (it returns the correct data first 4-5 tries then it starts on returning errors). I tried to use proxies but I returns error straight away. Any fixes? This is my code:

```
    url = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/dog/?__a=1&page=1"
    postLinks = []
    s = requests.session()
    r = s.get(url=url,proxies=proxy)
    xml_list = r.json()["graphql"]["hashtag"]["edge_hashtag_to_media"]["edges"]
    for xmls in xml_list:
            postLinks_list =  xmls["node"]
            if len(postLinks_list) > 0:
                    code = postLinks_list["shortcode"]
                    postLinks.append(code)
                    print("https://instagram.com/p/" + code)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make login request before g to explore there are a lot of tutorials in youtube explain how make login request.